# Reference to undefined identifier in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to run this scheme program from my book, yet whenever I try to evaluate (minus 5 4). The error: "reference to undefined identifier: minus" appears. Running the function as (minus 5 4) obviously doesn't work. Did I call the evaluation wrong?

```
(define (eval-expr E)
  (cond
    ((number? E) E)
    ((eqv? (car E) 'plus) (apply + (eval-params (cdr E))))
    ((eqv? (car E) 'times) (apply * (eval-params (cdr E))))
    ((eqv? (car E) 'minus) (apply - (eval-params (cdr E))))      
    ((eqv? (car E) 'divide) (apply / (eval-params (cdr E))))
    (else '()) ; confused - return ()
    )
  )

(define (eval-params E)
  (if (null? E) '()
      (cons (eval-expr (car E)) (eval-params (cdr E)))
      )
)
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want to call

```
(eval-expr '(minus 5 4))
```

The `eval-expr` function takes *data* that represents an arithmetic expression. On the other hand, your example `(minus 5 4)` is *code* that's trying to call a function called `minus`.

Comment: Looks like I got it. (eval-expr '(minus 5 4)) Thanks!